# BitBlt and COLORREF memory usage

Tags: c++, memory

I wrote a code that prints a COLORREF array to a window by BitBlt over an hdc. But it is using an enormous amount of memory. Not sure if by leaking or simply because of incorrect rendering method.

Need some alternative method that is more eficient and relatively easy to implement (its an already finished project and functions below are implemented hundreds of times) or an idea on how to fix it if leaking issues. (i can't use directx, opengl, etc, to render the scene).

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

//MODIFY AS YOU WISH
const int   MAX_FPS          = 0;    /*MAX FPS DISPLAYED SET TO 0 TO NO LIMIT
setting over 50 may cause performance drops */
const int   KEYBOARD_DELAY   = 2;     //DELAY IN MS OF THE KEYBOARD INPUT INCREASING IS FPS KILLER
const bool  DISPLAYFPS       = true;  //DISPLAY FPS COUNTER ON A CORNER OF THE SCREEN

//CODE START
const int   MAX_RES_X        = 1920; //MAX WINDOW WIDTH RESOLUTION. LESS USES LESS MEMORY
const int   MAX_RES_Y        = 1080; //HEIGHT RES

int MAP_WIDTH; //SCENE PROPERTIES
int MAP_HEIGHT;

HBITMAP map;
HWND hwnd; //HANDLE TO MAIN WINDOW
HDC hdc; //HANDLE TO HDC
MSG msg; //WINDOW MESSAGE

COLORREF *SCENE = (COLORREF*) calloc(MAX_RES_X*MAX_RES_Y, sizeof(COLORREF));    //MAIN SCENE BUFFER

void render_init_fullscreen(char const* title) {

  FreeConsole();

  HMONITOR hmon = MonitorFromWindow(GetActiveWindow(), MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST);
  MONITORINFO mi = { sizeof(mi) };
  if (!GetMonitorInfo(hmon, &mi)) return;
  hwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"),
        TEXT(title),
        (WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE),
        mi.rcMonitor.left,
        mi.rcMonitor.top,
        mi.rcMonitor.right - mi.rcMonitor.left,
        mi.rcMonitor.bottom - mi.rcMonitor.top,
        0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
  MAP_WIDTH=mi.rcMonitor.right;
  MAP_HEIGHT=mi.rcMonitor.bottom;

  ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT ) ;
  while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
  HDC hdc_tmp = GetDC(hwnd);
  hdc = hdc_tmp;

    SetCapture(hwnd);
}

void render_render() {
  map = CreateBitmap(MAP_WIDTH,
                             MAP_HEIGHT,
                             1,
                             4*8,
                             (void*) SCENE);

  HDC src = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
  SelectObject(src, map);
  BitBlt(hdc,
         0,
         0,
         MAP_WIDTH,
         MAP_HEIGHT,
         src,
         0,
         0,
         SRCCOPY);

  DeleteDC(src);
  while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
  }
}

long __stdcall WindowProcedure( HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp ) {
    switch(msg)
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            exit(0);
            return 0L ;
            break;
    }
    return DefWindowProc( window, msg, wp, lp ) ;

}
```

Comment: 1920 x 1080 x 4 = 8GB. Looks "normal" :) You can shrink to 4GB with 16 bit per pixel.

Comment: @i486 Thanks for your answer. When i change map size to 4*4 the window doesn't display anything. any fix idea?

Comment: If the image you copy into `SCENE` is always `MAX_RESX_...`, you can use `StretchBlt` instead of `BitBlt` to resize the image to a different destination size.  Something like: `StretchBlt(hdc, 0, 0, MAP_WIDTH, MAP_HEIGHT, src, 0, 0, MAX_RES_X, MAX_RES_Y, SRCCOPY);`